# ASP.NET WebControls DataGrid Get Selected Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I am using a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in an ASP.NET page.

When someone clicks a row with their mouse, I want to fill in data on my form using info from that DataGrid's Selected Row.

I have wired up the control's `SelectedIndexChanged` event, but there does not seem to be any way to access the individual rows.

```
protected void DataGridRow_Selected(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var row = grid1. ???
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

I use Windows Forms mostly, so I could be missing something completely obvious to people who use WebForms on a more frequent basis.

Comment: its going to be in e.Something  - SelectedRow  or something like that, i don't have VS open

Comment: Check this for various samples - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.selectedindex.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ajax like JQuery to get the content of that grid cell and populate to your form field.

```
$("#inputfield").value($("#gridcell").html())
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept this as an answer. I had to learn a bit of jQuery first! :P